# Cannot post a duplicate message on chat even after the first message is edited, chat eats up the second message

Tags: bug, chat

When you edit a message and repost the contents of  its first revision, the repost is eaten up by chat.

Steps to reproduce:

- Join any chat room
- Post something. Let's say you post `abcd`
- Edit that to something else. For example, `---`
- Try to post `abcd` again. The green (pending) message will show up, but when the response is received, it disappears (the server spits out `{"id":null,"time":null}` as the response)

This happens more often than you think. Many a time I post something, only to realize that I want to use the magic separator (`---`) to separate it from a previous block. So I up-arrow, Ctrl-X, and type `---`, and then I repost the cut text. Which gets eaten up by the server -- making a small change to the repost fixes things.

Comment: Chat hiding duplicate messages is intentional, I think, although I can't find a reference now. Possibly it shouldn't do that if the previous message was edited

Comment: Hm, no repro, but maybe I'm just too slow on mobile. Are you sure the edit went through before you posted the contents again? Like @MichaelMrozek said, it will intentionally eat consecutive duplicates if you post them too quickly.

Comment: @TimStone Just tried it, the response is received.

Comment: It turns out that you even [asked for that to be the case](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=203750#203750) before, @MichaelMrozek. Also, for reference, [here's a reference](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=177151#177151).

Comment: @TimStone Ah, I thought I'd posted about it before, but I couldn't find a meta question

Comment: Can still reproduce this issue. I've edited the title to make it more descriptive.